# compare splines and polynomials

Tags: r, function, regression, formula

I'm trying to write a function to compare the basic model between splines and polynomial regression.
But when I use `model$formula` option, that I have in my model, and use it into a `gam` function with the next variable, I receive an error:

> `Error in mod$formula + df_work_final$Apps :`
>   `non-numeric argument to binary operator`

How I can use my model formula into the function?

Thank You

Complete example:

```
library(gam)
library(ISLR)
data(College)

mod = gam(College$Grad.Rate~College$Private)

# This, I want to use into a function
Poly = function(valores){
    poly.1= gam(mod$formula + valores,data=College)
    poly.2= gam(mod$formula + poly(valores,2) ,data=College)
    poly.3= gam(mod$formula + poly(valores,3) ,data=College)
    poly.4= gam(mod$formula + poly(valores,4) ,data=College)
    poly.5= gam(mod$formula + poly(valores,5) ,data=College)
}

Poly(df_work_final$Apps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my previous comments into an answer:

- In any case, using `$` in a model formula should be **prohibited**; use `data` argument of model fitting functions instead;
- I don't see any smooth function in your initial `gam`, like `lo` or `s`. You are really just fitting a linear model `Grad.Rate ~ Private`. So, why not use

  ```
  mod <- lm(Grad.Rate ~ Private, data = College)
  ```
- `+` is invalid for concatenation of formula. You want to use `update.formula` (read `?update.formula` for more), for example,

  ```
  update.formula(formula(mod), . ~ . + poly(Apps, 2))
  ```